# run jar with `Error: Could not find or load main class`

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I create jar file by Intellij by these steps: File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> Click green plus sign -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies

I run it by `java -jar XX.jar`, but I get an error: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.guangyan.upf.Main`

there is my jar file look like:
[image]

How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When [creating the jar artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#package) make sure you have specified the directory for manifest file. Then add the main class in manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sample.Main
```

Or else you can follow this tutorial for how to create runnable jar artifact and run it [using Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html#deploy_gradle) in IntelliJ IDEA.